# Angular 2 this.data is undefined

Tags: json, angular, typescript, variables

I'm trying to read the content of my JSON file through my "GetJsonService".

**app.component.ts:**

```
data: any;

constructor(private jsonService: GetJsonService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getRecords();
    console.log(this.data);
}

getRecords() {
    this.jsonService.getRecords().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

**get-json.service.ts**

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }

data: any;

getRecords() {
    return this.http.get('assets/standorte.json').map(data => {
        this.data = data.json();
        return data.json();
    }, err => {
        if (err) {
            return err.json();
       }
     });
 }
```

I want to put the content of data.json() into this.data to use it.
But when I log this.data it is "undefined".

I'm completely new to Angular 2 and Typescript, so I really would be thankful when someone helps me.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MauricioSipmann solved my problem.
The problem was that the code runs asynchronously in a request.
I actually knew that but Typescript confused me a little bit.

Thank you to all responders!

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your method **getRecords()**

Use it as below :

```
getRecords() {
    this.jsonService.getRecords().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log(this.data);
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Instead of logging after calling method you should do inside success of service.

This is common issue which every developer face at initiate stage of Angular 2+.
It is an **async** call. So the issue is you **console.log()** statement is executing before your service assign value **this.data = data;** to the variable.

With your code if you display **data** in HTML it will probably work fine. Just it will not log properly where you got confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 6, no need to convert to json. Just return the request.

```
getRecords() {
  return this.http.get('assets/standorte.json') 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another problem is your not re throw the async state ..try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getRecords().then((resp)=>{
console.log(resp);
});

}

getRecords() {
return new Promise<>((resolve,reject)
 => {
   this.jsonService.getRecords().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;

resolve(data);
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
reject(err);
    });

})
}
```